# Develop Visualforce Pages using Ext JS

Tags: extjs, visualforce

I believe Salesforce has started using Ext JS. Just curious to know if anyone has tried using Ext JS with Visualforce. I tried it but seems causing some conflict with existing Ext JS of Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Does Ext JS support a compatibility option similar to jQuery? With jQuery I always make the first line of my javascript `jQuery.noConflict();` and from then onwards always use `jQuery(".class")` rather than `$(".class")` for instance, this prevents me from having conflict issues with the jQuery file that SFDC includes automatically on each page.